# Select where two layers deep

Tags: sql

I really did not know how to word the title of this sentence or how to search for my solution, so I decided to ask here.

Essentially I have three tables - `events`, `announcers`, and `media`. Media contains a foreign key that refers to an announcer, and each announcer has a foreign key that refers to an event. My goal is to SELECT all media that is from a certain event.

I apologize if my question is repetitive, but I could not figure out the search term to give me my solution.

Say my events table contains the following info:

- Name: varchar(200)
- Id (PK): int

My announcers table is:

- Name: varchar(200)
- Id (PK): int
- event_id (FK - events): int

And my media table:

- media_id: varchar(32)
- Id (PK): int
- announcer_id (FK - announcers): int

If events table contains the following event, Name: Birthday Party, ID: 1

And announcers contains:

- Name: Speech1, Id: 1, event_id: 1
- Name: Speech2, Id: 2, event_id: 1

And media contains:

- media_id: (some id), Id: 1, announcer_id: 1
- media_id: (some id), Id: 2, announcer_id: 1
- media_id: (some id), Id: 3, announcer_id: 2
- media_id: (some id), Id: 4, announcer_id: 2

The query that I want to run should return all media.

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I have just added some test data and expected result.

Comment: please mention database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
--whatever attributes you want to display from e,a,m
m.* 
FROM
event  e
INNER JOIN 
announcer a 
ON
e.id = a.event_id 
INNER JOIN
 media m 
ON 
 a.id = m.announcer_id 
 WHERE e.attribute_name = value 
 --(or any condition)
```